# how to show code snippet on ASP.NET page with color formatting

Tags: asp.net

I want to show code in asp.net page , how to show code snippet that it will look in same colors as it looks in visual studio , best examlple i can give is this stackoverflow.com itself we can put code fragment in our question which looks well colored giving better user exprience

i have just no clue ? also how to store code snippets when user enters them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StackOverflow uses [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) for syntax highlighting.

What do you mean by how to store code snippets? You might want to post that as a separate question with a little more detail.

Comment: i mean if my code snippets are stored in database as varchar(max) or comming from some word document. Is it possible to format it ? 
but thanks , your answer helped

Comment: @Ajax2020, yes. Have a look at the README file for prettify. Basically you just need to output the text and wrap it in a `<pre class="prettyprint">` or `<code class="prettyprint">`

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to start with [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)  which is the same code coloring tool used here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

The solution you're looking for is called syntax highlighting.

Prettify is a popular one, but I've used [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter) before and it is quite nice.

> SyntaxHighlighter helps developers to
>   display code on their website.

Also, Syntax Highlighter recently added a hosted syntax highlighter "service."

- [About Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter:About)
- [Hosted Version of Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter:Hosting)

Extra:  [Shanselman Speaks on Syntax Highlighting](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BestCodeSyntaxHighlighterForSnippetsInYourBlog.aspx)